# Multiple joint and conditional entropy

Tags: probability, information-theory, entropy

While studying the chain rule for information entropy, I got confused as to its meaning. The rule states:

> H(X, Y|Z) = H(X|Z) + H(Y|X, Z)

What then is the difference between $H(X, Y|Z)$ and $H(Y|Z, X)$?

I am wondering whether in $H(X, Y|Z)$ the pipe (|) has precedence so that entropy of the tuple $(X, Y)$ is considered when $Z$ is known or the comma (,) has precedence so that the entropy of the tuple (X, Y) happens which is $Y$ only depends when $Z$ is known?

What about $H(X, Y|Z, Q|K)$? Is there is any rule to understand this notation?

I'm very confused because $H(X, Y|Z)$ and $H(Y|Z, X)$ are not the same even though $H(X, Y) = H(Y, X)$ is valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In topics linked to probability and statistics, the pipe symbol | usually means "given": it denotes data known beforehand. For instance, taking two events $A$ and $B$ from a universe $\Omega$, the expression $P(A|B)$ denotes the probability of event $A$ happening, knowing that event $B$ has happened.

For probabilities, this notation denotes conditional probability. In information theory, when talking about *Shannon entropy*, it denotes conditional entropy (which is computed using conditional probability).

To further elaborate, let us take two random variables $X$ and $Y$ respectively taking values in sets $A$ and $B$. 
The Shannon entropy of $X$ is then (by convention, for values of $x$ where $P_X(x) = 0$, the term in the sum is considered to be $0$):

$H(X) = -\sum_{x \in A}P_X(x) \log{[P_X(x)]}$

The *conditional entropy* of $X$ given $Y = y$ is:

$H(X|Y=y) = -\sum_{x \in A}P_{X|Y}(x|y) \log{[P_{X|Y}(x|y)]}$

The conditional entropy of $X$ given $Y$ is then the weighted average of the previously defined entropy over all values of $Y$:

$H(X|Y) = -\sum_{x \in A, y \in B}P_Y(y)P_{X|Y}(x|y) \log{[P_{X|Y}(x|y)]} = -\sum_{x \in A, y \in B}P_{X,Y}(x,y) \log{[P_{X|Y}(x|y)]}$

Moving on to the comma notation, it denotes joint probability and thus joint entropy. In other words, $P_{X,Y}(x,y)$ can also be written as $P(X = x, Y = y)$.

Combining these two concepts, $P_{X,Y|Z}(x,y|z)$ denotes the probability of $(X,Y)$ taking the value $(x, y)$, knowing $Z$. The conditional entropy $H(X,Y|Z)$ makes use of this probability:

$H(X,Y|Z=z) = -\sum_{(x,y) \in A \times B}P_{X,Y|Z}(x,y|z) \log{P_{X,Y|Z}(x,y|z)}$

$H(X,Y|Z) = -\sum_{(x,y,z) \in A \times B \times C}P_{X,Y,Z}(x,y,z) \log{P_{X,Y|Z}(x,y|z)}$

Now that we have the basics down, we can move on to your questions.

First of all, $H(X,Y|Z)$ is the entropy of $X$ and $Y$ together (taking the value $(x,y)$) when the value of $Z$ is given, while $H(Z|X,Y)$ is the entropy of $Z$ when the values of $X$ and $Y$ are given.

There is no real rule to understand $H(X,Y|Z,Q|K)$ and I strongly doubt you will ever see this notation in any reputable textbook.

Finally, $H(X,Y|Z)$ and $H(Z|X,Y)$ cannot be equivalent, as you need to know the value of $Z$ for the first one and the value of $X$ and $Y$ for the second one.

As a rule of thumb, uppercase letters denote random variables, whereas lowercase letters denote actual numbers.

As an addendum, I would like to explain the chain rule (in its reduced format as you mention it in your questions). Seeing as entropy is a measure of uncertainty, we can say that the formula $H(X,Y|Z) = H(X|Z) + H(Y|X,Z)$ means: the uncertainty of $X$ and $Y$ knowing $Z$ is the uncertainty of $X$ knowing $Z$ plus the uncertainty of $Y$ knowing $X$ and $Z$ (since after the first term you've found out the actual value of $X$).